# Fresh MySQL data via query using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python script that read data from a MySQL db. There a table called ORARI and basically 3 fields: ID, acceso,spento. I need to read acceso, spento every 10 seconds. ACCESO and SPENTO are edited via a web interface, so they may vary. The problem is that when I run my script i can see the exact data from the db, but when I make a change to these values, the python script show me the initial value, not the updated value.

```
while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        dateString = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        orario = ("SELECT * FROM orari WHERE attivo = 1")
        cur.execute(orario)
        row = cur.fetchone()
        acceso = row[1]
        spento = row[2]
        print acceso
        print dateString
        print spento
```

Comment: @incredibleHat it's a test i'm making to see if it works like this. This is a simplified version of a bigger script i'm working on to present You only this particular problem i'm having and not the whole code. Not for keep it secret or something like that; I know this is rude but it works to explain my need

Comment: @roganjosh Since he had php as a tag, and seeing `while true` ... in php land, that would basically crater your script with an endless loop. Now since the php tags been removed, my comment makes no sense, because in python, it behaves differently.

Comment: @IncredibleHat in Python it will still cause an endless loop, but `time.sleep(10)` would stop you clobbering the database with queries since it's all executed sequentially (and you could always call `break` at any time for some condition not relevant to this question). I don't know anything about PHP but are you suggesting this would have just been a mass of async requests?

Comment: It most likely would have gotten away from the user ;) I get a little frightened when I see a loop designed like that (relying on an inner break to happen). Anyhoo, looks like Luca got things straightened away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to insert, after the query: db.commit()